# Send email in laravel by using mailtrap

Tags: php, laravel

Hello this my project with laravel to send an email by using mailtrap 
 this is my sendemail controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use App\Model\Sendemail;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Mail;
 use App\Mail\TestStarted;
 class SendemailController extends Controller
{
  public function start(Request $request)
 {

    $send_email = Mail::to($request->email)->send(new TestStarted);
    if ($send_email) 
     {
   return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Sens email 
  successfully.');        
     }
 }
}
```

and this function to share the approval student into studentcontroller

```
public function shareapproval($uniid)
{
$approval = Student :: where ('uniid', $uniid)->firstOrFail();
return view('SendEmail.Request.share',compact('approval'));
}
```

and this TestStarted.php in Mail file

```
<?php
namespace App\Mail;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class TestStarted extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('SendEmail.Request.mail');
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Sens email successfully.');
}
}
```

this is in config.mail.php

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'testgp2@system.com'),//
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

and this is my form to write the instructor email to send the email

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
<form method="post" action="/sendemail">
@csrf
 <h1>  send email </h1>
  <br>
  <<div class="form-group">
   <label for="email">write the instructor email</label><br>
   <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" >
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">send </button><br>
  </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

and this is the content of mail I want to send it 
this is mail.blade.php in (resources\views\SendEmail\Request\mail.blade.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-enguiv="X-UA-compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>document </titel>
 </head>

 <body background-color: coral>
<h2> thank you for your order </h2>

</body
</html>
```

Finally, this is my route

```
Route::post('/student/share-approval/{uniid}', 
 'StudentController@shareapproval');

//SendEmail
Route::post('/sendemail','SendemailController@start');
Route::get('/start','SendemailController@start');
```

and I set up my .env with MAIL_USERNAME and MAIL_PASSWORD as shown in my account on mailtrap

Comment: What is the actual issue you are having? Do you see an error?

Comment: Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. #10061]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's start from the route. You're pointing the same method for the GET and POST request:

```
Route::post('/sendemail','SendemailController@start');
Route::get('/start','SendemailController@start');
```

As a result the mail field `Mail::to($request->email)` is getting null. Which could be a reason behind failure. So try to use different methods for handling GET and POST requests instead of one.

```
Route::get('/start','SendemailController@start');
Route::post('/sendemail','SendemailController@sendMail');
```

Secondly, in the code below, you are returning twice. But in real life it will only execute the first one and ignore the second one.

```
public function build()
{
    // this is executing
    return $this->view('SendEmail.Request.mail');
    // this is getting ingorned
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Sens email successfully.');
}
```

Comment: In that case, you need to add the method sendMail in the SendemailController, where you need to put send mail stuff

Comment: Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. #10061]

Comment: can you share your .env file or particularly the mailtrap section

Comment: write your email to send it to you